Type of array containing path
I'm doing some work on a library which tracks validation errors in a structure as follows:
type ValidationErrors = {path: (string|number)[], message:string,...}[]
Where path is actually a series of indexes/components of a known type for example if this was for an object of type {a:{b:number, c:string}[], x? :{y:boolean, z:string|null}, w:string} some valid path arrays might be ["a", 0, "c"], ["w"], ["x", "y"], ["a", 5], []
With this explained. How do I write a type ValidationPath<T> such that only valid paths down T are acceptable?
I've tried numerous permutations of using conditional types & infer but nothing has seemed to work either I end up with something that accepts everything or something that accepts only 1 layer then fails.

The relationship between {a:{b:number, c:string}[], x? :{y:boolean, z:string|null}, w:string} and ["a", 0, "c"], ["w"], ["x", "y"], ["a", 5], [] is not clear to me. Can you edit the question to provide a detailed explanation of the relationship?

you can use the Paths type from the type-fest utility library: https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining or find a suitable dupe target; if not, what am I missing?
